# Does flask return multiple videos?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, computer-vision, mediapipe

```
def gen_frames():  
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
    
    counter = 0 
    stage = None
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', frame)
            if not ret:
                frame = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                continue
        
            else:            
            ## Setup mediapipe instance
            
                
                 # Recolor image to RGB
                image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image.flags.writeable = False

                # Make detection
                results = pose.process(image)

                # Recolor back to BGR
                image.flags.writeable = True
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                
                # Render detections
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                        mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                        mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2) 
                                         )        
                cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
                ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
                frame=buffer.tobytes()
            
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                      b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame + b'\r\n')
```

```
def gen_expert():  
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
    
    counter = 0 
    stage = None
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
    
        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow('Mediapipe Feed', frame)
            if not ret:
                frame = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                continue
        
            else:            
            ## Setup mediapipe instance
            
                
                 # Recolor image to RGB
                image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                image.flags.writeable = False

                # Make detection
                results = pose.process(image)

                # Recolor back to BGR
                image.flags.writeable = True
                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                
                # Render detections
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                        mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=2), 
                                        mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2) 
                                         )        
                cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
                ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
                frame=buffer.tobytes()
            
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                      b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame + b'\r\n')
```

```
@app.route('/video')
def video():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/expert')
def Getexpert():
    return Response(gen_expert(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

When I run my program on flask(I am making home training program using opencv on flask now), only app.route('/video') is running. I don't know why @app.route('/expert') isn't running but I think flask (or opencv) can't read multiple videos. (or can't return multiple videos)
I see many kinds of returning only one video but i did't see returning multiple videos
So Does flask return only one video?

Comment: that is an interesting question.  do you have two different capture devices ?

Comment: oh wait a  second

Comment: i was going to suggest deeper checks, but its always the obvious things...

Comment: because of content capacity, i can't upload capture pictures... hmmm i

Comment: can we meet at zoom? I have zoom service, i mean charged one

Comment: you would have to message me on twiter (in my profle). i am not sure exchange of details is allowed (or the done thing) here ?

Comment: okay i sent message for you!